# error when method Depends on result of background method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

I have method `get_all_emails` return all emails by some condition . when call this method inside other method and pass result as arg to method

```
def send_mail 
    emails = Mail.get_emails_list(Mail::EMAIL)
    validate_emails = get_validate(emails , true)
    if validate_emails != ''
      puts "hello"
    end

end
```

appear this error

> "error": "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"

when read some article can convert `get_validate` to background less `priority` but if not know this is optimal solution or not . if exist solution without this solution convert `get_validate` to background

I use `rails 5.2` & gem `delayed_job_active_record`

more info for error

```
rails server 

AlertMai#send_mail: processed outbound mail in 243.7ms

Postman appear this 
500Internal Server Error
{
    "error": "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"
}
```

Comment: seems that the `get_all_emails` or another method was defined with no argument but used with an argument. can you add this method?

Comment: `get_validate`  need argument when pass this `   emails = Mail.get_emails_list(Mail::EMAIL)
` not pass to this method . @ekremkaraca

Comment: can you add more details about error, if it is possible?

Comment: @ekremkaraca yes sure i add it .